# ActiveRecord nested associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have some models like `Service`, `Payment` and `Manager`

```
class Service < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true

  has_and_belongs_to_many :tickets
  has_many :payments
end

class Payment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :manager
  belongs_to :service
  validates :value, :manager_id, :service_id, presence: true
end

class Manager < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

`Service` can have multiple `Payment`s and each `Payment` has single `Manager`.

I want to get the whole data using all nested associations as a hash that I could reformat (or map) and sent to the client. I am stuck with query:

```
Service.includes(payments: :manager).references(:payments, :managers)
```

as it is using lazy load, and I need to do something like:

```
services.first.payments.first.manager
```

to get data, and it is non-optimal.

Is it possible to get all data with all nested associations?

I did calculations like this:

```
services = Service.includes(payments: :manager)
                   .references(:payments, :managers)

  result = []

  services.each do |service|
    service.payments.each do |payment|
      manager_name = payment[:manager][:name]
      value = payment[:value]

      service[manager_name] = value
    end

    result.push(service)
  end
```

and got an error `NoMethodError (undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass):`
on `manager_name = payment[:manager][:name]` line.

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is, can you show some console output maybe to make it clear what you're seeing?

Comment: How many services there are on the database? The solution depends on the size of data.

Comment: In fact size of data doesn't matter, I want to have unique solution to get all data at once. Please refer to edited topic.

Comment: @Dmitry Is not `service` instance of  `Service` class? But you treat it as hash like `service[manager_name] = value`. I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an additional has_many through relationship which should give you what you want.

**has_many :managers, through: :payments**

```
class Service < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true

  has_and_belongs_to_many :tickets
  has_many :payments

  has_many :managers, through: :payments
end

class Payment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :manager
  belongs_to :service
  validates :value, :manager_id, :service_id, presence: true
end

class Manager < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your need %100 but I come up and idea like following. Please review it.

```rb
payments = Payment.joins(:service).select(:service_id, :manager_id, :value).
    group_by(&:service_id)

managers = Manager.where('id IN(SELECT manager_id FROM payments)').
    select(:name,:id)
    group_by(&:id).transform_values{ |value| value.first }


result = []
ResultClass = Struct.new(:service, :manager, :payment_value)
Service.all.each do |service|
  payment = payments[service.id]
  manager = managers[payment.manager_id]
  result << ResultClass.new(service, manager, payment.value)
end
```

With this code, we are actually trying to accomplish rails `includes` mechanism under the hood. What we did actually here?

- We get the payments and converted them to hash that the id is hash key
- Then we get the managers those have payments and we converted also these records  with manager id as hash key
- We created `ResultClass` with `Struct` to store the references of objects like `service` and `manager`
- We start the iteration. Because of the fact that we have `payments` and `members` as hash, there is fast look up and there is no time complexity. In overall, this iteration's time complexity is O(n)

If you have any questions please feel free to drop a comment.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of tries I've finally find some misspells I made and archieved behaviour I want using such code

```
services = Service.eager_load(payments: :manager)

  services.reduce([]) do |acc, service|
    service_rec = {
      id: service[:id],
      name: service[:name],
      surgery: service[:surgery]
    }

    service.payments.each do |payment|
      manager_name = payment.manager[:name]
      value = payment[:value]

      service_rec[manager_name] = value
    end

    acc.push(service_rec)
  end
```

and SQL query it produces

```
SQL (0.2ms)  SELECT "services"."id" AS t0_r0, "services"."code" AS t0_r1, "services"."name" AS t0_r2, "services"."surgery" AS t0_r3, "services"."enabled" AS t0_r4, "services"."created_at" AS t0_r5, "services"."updated_at" AS t0_r6, "payments"."id" AS t1_r0, "payments"."service_id" AS t1_r1, "payments"."manager_id" AS t1_r2, "payments"."value" AS t1_r3, "payments"."created_at" AS t1_r4, "payments"."updated_at" AS t1_r5, "managers"."id" AS t2_r0, "managers"."name" AS t2_r1, "managers"."enabled" AS t2_r2, "managers"."created_at" AS t2_r3, "managers"."updated_at" AS t2_r4 FROM "services" LEFT OUTER JOIN "payments" ON "payments"."service_id" = "services"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "managers" ON "managers"."id" = "payments"."manager_id"
```

It is interesting that using `includes` instead of `eager_load` produces three queries instead

```
Service Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "services".* FROM "services"
  ↳ app/services/payments_service.rb:6
  Payment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "payments".* FROM "payments" WHERE "payments"."service_id" IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["service_id", 1], ["service_id", 2], ["service_id", 3], ["service_id", 4], ["service_id", 5], ["service_id", 6], ["service_id", 7], ["service_id", 8]]
  ↳ app/services/payments_service.rb:6
  Manager Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "managers".* FROM "managers" WHERE "managers"."id" IN (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["id", 1], ["id", 2], ["id", 3], ["id", 4]]
```

Also we can use `Service.includes(payments: :manager).references(:payments, :managers)` and got the same query as `eager_load` but it's longer to type))

Thanks everyone for participation! Does anyone have another opinion about `eager_load` or code optimisation proposals?

Comment: Did you test my approach? What is the output of my approach? Would you mind me if you share it?

Comment: @zeitnot sorry I didn't test you code, it seems too complicated to me (maybe because I'm activerecord noob)) anyway why we need 3 queries if we can get data using single and simple query?

Comment: Well actually, I did not really understand your needs. So I thought that you had some problems with rails's `includes` and I did a workaround for that. You would want compare my solution and your solution in terms of speed. I am not sure which is the best because you have the data.